# How to apply the fore color and bold in message text using c#..net

Tags: c#, asp.net

i am displaying the one confirm box after saving the values like this

```
showalert("Quote has been saved successfully. Your Submission Number is:" + SaveValue );
```

now i have display the savevalue bold and underline and some fore color, how to apply(using any format and html styles also)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could create your own javascript popup alert.

```
    function ShowAlert(message) {
      $('#popup').fadeIn(500);
      $('#popupmessage').html(message);
    };
```

Your html could be something like this

```
    <div id="popup" class="window">
  <p id="popupmessage"></p>
</div>
```

your code behind could then be

```
    ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(),"AlertScript","ShowAlert('Quote has been saved successfully. Your Submission Number is:<span style='text-decoration:underline;'>" + SaveValue + "</span>);"), true);
```

This way you can display a popup message and style it to your needs.

Comment: it is not working , any supporting file are added in my project pls give me some suggestion

Comment: Ok, make sure you have a link to Jquery on your page, second make sure in the code behind (set a breakpoint) that its hitting the ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how to change the style as your way, but here is [another alternative](http://great.blog.35.cn/archives/130)(it's written in chinese but the code is not):

Answer (score 0):

```
function ShowAlert(message) {    
   $('#popup').fadeIn(500);
var newmessage = "<span style='color:red;font-weight:bold;text-decoration:underline'>" + message + "</span>";
$('#popupmessage').html(newmessage); 
    };
```